# Why doesn't the Update Message Fire when I update a customeraddress from the Account screen

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

As I understand, an account entity in Dyanimcs CRM has two child customeraddress entities attached.  In the account form, when you edit the address information and click save, I would expect that an update would be registered on the customeraddress entity.

I'm working on a plugin that will help sychronize our addresses across our enterprise, and when an edit happens on the CRM server it needs to make sure that it propagates to our other systems.

In writing some diagnostic code, I wrote a quick wcf server that will allow me to examine the entities as they exist at execution. However this plugin only fires when the actual Address form is used for the edit, not when the account form is being edited.

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (serviceProvider == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("serviceProvider");
        }

        // Construct the Local plug-in context.
        ITracingService localcontext = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
        localcontext.Trace(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Entered {0}.Execute()", "AuditAddressChange"));

        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        var WCFDebug = ChannelFactory<IService1>.CreateChannel(new BasicHttpBinding(),
           new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8732/WcfDebug"));

        try
        {
            Entity e = context.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity;
            if (e != null)
            {
                foreach (var attribute in e.Attributes)
                {
                    WCFDebug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ==> {1}", attribute.Key, attribute.Value.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> e)
        {
            localcontext.Trace(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Exception: {0}", e.ToString()));

            // Handle the exception.
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            localcontext.Trace(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Exiting {0}.Execute()", "AuditAddressChange"));
        }
    }
```

This plugin is registered to fire on the customeraddress update post step.

Given that this plug-in executes correctly when an edit happens from an Address Form, why doesn't this fire when the edit happens from the account form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two addresses are handled like they were part of the account record. Internally the data of the address1 and address2 fields are stored in two customeraddress records.

In the viewpoint of the user and the SDK they are part of the account record. That's why your plugin isn't triggered.

In order to handle the address changes for account (regarding the address1 and address2 fields), you have to handle the Update-Message for account. For all other customeraddress  records, you have to handle the Update-Message for customeraddress .

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid of this. Do you happen to have a link to documentation on this?

Comment: @fauxtrot sry. not atm. Give me some time, I'll try to find something for you

Comment: I couldn't find the documentation, but your explaination is reasonable.  I'm going to +1 and mark as answer.  Thank you!